# Emulate button in qemu-stm32

Tags: stm32, qemu

I run `button` demo from https://github.com/beckus/stm32_p103_demos on qemu-stm32 https://github.com/beckus/qemu_stm32

I can see LED blinking in `led_blink` demo as text "Led ON" in the console but how do I emulate a button press?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the [`button_int` demo](https://github.com/beckus/stm32_p103_demos/tree/master/demos/button_int).

From https://github.com/beckus/stm32_p103_demos/blob/master/README:

```
button_int -
    Example of external interrupts.  Toggles the LED every time the
    button is pressed.  Note that in QEMU, the button press is simulated
    by pressing the b key.  You will need to do this from the QEMU monitor,
    by typing the command "sendkey b".
```

According to the readme, the `button` demo doesn't always work:

```
button -
    Example of using the button in non-interrupt mode.  Continuously polls
    the button and toggles the LED when the button is pressed.  Note that this
    example does not seem to work well in QEMU.  When using "sendkey b"
    (see the button_int demo below), the LED does not toggle.  Perhaps
    this is a timing issue?
```